# Путь содержит недопустимые знаки C#

Tags: c#

При обращении к файлу выдает исключение:

```
System.TypeInitializationException: Инициализатор типа "coursework_project.Form1" выдал исключение. ---> System.ArgumentException: Путь содержит недопустимые знаки.
```

Проблема в строке

```
string[] country_array = File.ReadAllLines(Resources.index);
```

Путь до файла:
`C:\Users\1\source\repos\coursework_project\coursework_project\resourses\index.txt`, кириллицы в пути нет

Comment: А путь разве в Resource. index должен находиться? Чёт сомнительно.

Comment: @AK добавил в визуалке в файл ресурсов, сам текстовый файл находится по пути выше

Comment: `string[] country_array = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\1\source\repos\coursework_project\coursework_project\resourses\index.txt");` вот в таком виде оно сработает?

Comment: `Console.WriteLn(Resources.index);` - ?

Comment: @tym32167 да, с прямым путём работает. Но нужно "вшить" текстовый файл в проект (то бишь юзать ресурсы), чтобы при запуске exe-шника на другом пк не нужно было бы скачивать отдельно txt файл.Как раз с ресурсами проблема и возникает

Comment: @Igor `WriteLine`

Comment: @Igor работа с консолью не подходит, т.к. в проекте юзается Windows Forms

Comment: А если вы `index.txt` с приложением переместите в другую папку, оно перестанет работать. Потому что путь абсолютный.

Comment: В студии серое окно Output/Вывод. Когда ваше приложение работает в режиме отладки, там видно будет, что выводит `Console.WriteLine`. Так же можно использовать `Debug.WriteLine`.

Comment: @Pr0va1der Это неважно. Важно значение `Resources.index`.

Comment: @Igor текст из файла достается

Comment: @Pr0va1der "текст из файла достается" - что это значит? Кому достается? Чему равно `Resources.index`?

Comment: @Igor Resources.Index равен тексту в текстовом файле. (В моем проекте это список стран)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Resources.Index равен тексту в текстовом файле.

```
//string[] country_array = File.ReadAllLines(Resources.index);
string[] country_array = Resources.index.Split("\n", System.StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Comment: Спасибо, добрый человек

Comment: @Pr0va1der На здоровье. Успехов.